# Google map mobile jquery api Location and Direction

Tags: google-maps-api-3, jquery-mobile

Hey I'm new with google map api. Please let me know if I can make an app which shows current location and direction at the same time.

Comment: off course you can, please do a google search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jQuery mobile with Google maps v3 plugin](http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-mobile-example.html).

[Google maps v3 plugin for jQuery, jQuery UI and jQuery Mobile](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/)  takes away some of the head aches from working with the Google Map API. Instead of having to use Google event listeners for simple events like click, you can use jQuery click events on the map and markers.

[Exmaples]
[Basic map example](http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-mobile-example.html#basic_map)
[Basic map example with geolocation](http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-mobile-example.html#gps_map)